# GNU Core Utilities - How exactly do 'ls', 'dir' and 'vdir' differ?

Tags: ls, coreutils

From `ls --help`, `dir --help`, `vdir --help` I notice there's no difference at all except for program names (the 'Usage: ' line and a few lines at the bottom). However `vdir` seems to be some kind of an alias of `ls -l`, while `dir` seems like making no difference. Can anyone tell me what are the *exact* differences among them?

Comment: aren't dir & vdir just aliases to variations of ls?

Comment: @JeffSchaller They are 3 separate binary executables in GNU Core Utilities. That's the reason for the title.

Comment: ok; first google hit made it look like an alias: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/vdir-invocation.html

Comment: this doesn't explain why they had to make dir and vdir separate executables instead of hardlinks to ls; a lot of programs work differently by checking the argv0 (eg. ex vs vi); why aren't they doing the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- From `info dir`: *`dir` is equivalent to `ls -C -b`*
- From `info vdir`: *`vdir` is equivalent to `ls -l -b`*

On an Ubuntu system I have, they appear to be the same binary (they have same exact size), but are not linked to each other, but I assume they could be:

```
$ ls -li /bin/{ls,dir,vdir}
131116 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 126584 Feb 18  2016 /bin/dir
131160 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 126584 Feb 18  2016 /bin/ls
131261 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 126584 Feb 18  2016 /bin/vdir
```

On my OpenBSD system, the sizes differ in a way that makes me think that the only thing that differs between them is the name of the utility stored in the binary itself:

```
$ ls -li /usr/local/bin/{gls,gdir,gvdir}
390089 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  bin  191244 Dec 30 12:31 /usr/local/bin/gdir
390113 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  bin  191243 Dec 30 12:31 /usr/local/bin/gls
390185 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  bin  191245 Dec 30 12:31 /usr/local/bin/gvdir
```

Comment: on ubuntu 22.04, although the binaries are the same size, they differ (`cmp`/`sum`/etc). the source indicates [`dir`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/coreutils-dir.c) and [`vdir`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/coreutils-vdir.c) are thin wrappers around the `ls` code. Presumably the compiler optimises away the tail call.